# How do I route Devise to a welcome screen on first login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How do I tell Devise to route the user to a one-time welcome screen when he has just registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Application controller, add this:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  some_special_page
end
```

For most of Devise-related questions, hit up their [Github wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages)

Answer (score 3):

Make a new controller "RegistrationsController" and customize the appropriate method:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    some_special_page
  end
end
```

If the account that is registered is not active yet, you have to override after_inactive_sign_up_path_for method.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    some_special_page
  end
end
```

Modify config/routes.rb to use the new controller

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

Source: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-after-registration-(sign-up)

Answer (score 1):

by default Devise will forward user to: user_root (if your model name is user)

so you can define named route

```
get "/welcome" => "welcomes#index", :as => "user_root"
```